# Magento 2 - Send form data to Controller using AJAX and return Result to PHTML

Tags: ajax, module, controller, magento2

I am working on a simple custom module, where user can input height and the weight/BMI will be shown as output on form submit. The page where user enters input is `Calculation` Page while output is shown on `Result` Page.On clicking the submit button user will be redirected to different controller/action. Below is the code

**Calculation Layout - Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/calculation_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" name="calculation_index" template="Vendor_Module::calculation.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Calculation Input PHTML -Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/calculation.phtml**

```
<div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <form name="height" method="POST" id="height">
                  <div class="well">
                    <strong><?php echo __('Enter Height:')?></strong>
                    <input type="text" id="calculateTotalInput" name="calculateTotalInput" class="form-control input-md">
                    <input type="submit" id="calculateTotalSubmit"  name="calculate-total-submit" value="Calculate Total">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
                    <?php echo __('Height:')?> <input type="text" value="<?= $weight ?>" name="height" class="form-control input-md" readonly="">
                    <?php echo __('BMI:')?> <input type="text" value="<?= $bmi ?>" name="weight" class="form-control input-md" readonly="">
                </div> 

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#height").submit(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/vendor/module/result/result",
        type: "POST",
        data: {height:height,weight:weight},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Block - Vendor/Module/Block/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Index extends Template
{

    public function __construct(Context $context,      
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }

    public function getAjaxData()
    {
        return $this->getData();
    }
}
```

**Calculation Controller - Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class Index extends Action
{

    /**
    * @var PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;


    /**
    * Result constructor.
    * @param Context $context
    * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
    */
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    /**
    * The controller action
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
    */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Result Page Controller -  Vendor/Module/Controller/Result/Result.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

     /**
     * @var Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    /**
     * @param Context     $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
        )
    {

        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data');
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Index')
                ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::result.phtml')
                ->setData('data',$data)
                ->toHtml();

        $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
        return $result;
    } 
}
```

**Result Layout File - Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/calculation_result_result.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <title>Result</title>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" name="calculation_index" template="Vendor_Module::result.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Result PHTML file - Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml**

```
<?php 

    echo $block->getAjaxData();

?>
```

> The workflow - user comes on calculation.phtml page > enters input >
>   call result ctrl via ajax on button submit > process data in result
>   ctrl > show the data in updated result.html with page reload.

- While trying to call controller action using AJAX, it is not working.
  How do I call and pass data to controller via AJAX ?
- How do I return data from controller in JSON format and send it back
  to result.phtml file in order to show the output ?

Comment: Please refer this link for appropriate answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158541/magento-2-how-to-send-data-using-ajax-form-in-custom-form